# Android Face recognition & get similar faces from the database

Tags: android, image, opencv, face-recognition, google-image-search

In my application I'm going to implement an image search like Google image search. Only difference is here I'm searching only for human faces. Here's how it goes..

- user take a picture of a person using the camera.
- my app should identify the face of that person and get details from the image regarding the face (eg: colors).
- Using those details app will do a search in the image database for similar faces.
- Finally it'll display results to the user.

So I want to recognize faces using Android face recognition class and select that recognized area and save the details of that face into an array or a database.

I got few questions on above scenario.

- what are the things I need from that image to do a proper image search?
- Can I do it only using colors?
- Do you have any idea on getting pixel details from that recognized face? I know how to do it on bitmap images. But i'm not sure that method still works with the face recognition class.

Can anyone explain those thing to me please?

Comment: http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~silvio/teaching/EECS598_2010/presentation/Aditya_Srujan.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [OpenCV's Recognition](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html) API.

I wrote a bit about how to set it up in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554067/setting-up-android-with-opencv/14557005#14557005).

Comment: isn't it available in JAVA so that i can use it in My Android Project ??? Can you be more specific to Android Link of Open CV

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you too to use OpenCV functions, they are well optimized for face detection and recognition .

for recognition, you don't need to colour processing. 
Since you develop your application on Android,  you can use [OpenCV4Android](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html)

Here there some helpful links, that let you have a good idea to start:

[Face Recognition on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699744/face-recognition-on-android)

Here you find a useful tutorial for face detection and recognition

http://www.shervinemami.info/faceRecognition.html

I also recommend you to apply the detection api that already implemented in android stuff:

http://pi-virtualworld.blogspot.com.br/2013/04/android-opencv-face-detection.html

In order to prepare a clean and a proper face database, which in turn enhance the goodness of recognition results, don' forget to align faces 
http://bytefish.de/blog/aligning_face_images/

Try and test already benchmark face database, to evaluate your implementation:

http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/lfw/#deepfunnel-anchor

http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/dtg/attarchive/facedatabase.html

Comment: thank you for so many links