# Use Processing and Opencv For android development?

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, image-recognition

Does anyone know if you can use the **OpenCV** library within the processing **Android template**? I want to do some image recognition/comparison for these devices within Processing.
    What are the means to do such? and does anyone have an example of source code for it?
        Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest just trying it and seeing if it works. This is not a programming problem that you are stuck on, but something you can easily verify on your own.

Comment: Noah, please consider either upvoting or acceptign my answer, or providing one of your own if you've managed to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenCV library that you would normally use (http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/) will not work for Android.

However, Android has it's own port of OpenCV, which is available here: http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html

That being said, it is a little tricky to setup itself vis-a-vis Processing, particularly if you are using the PDE. *If* you are using Eclipse & Processing together, then this answer may be useful to you: [OpenCV on Android Using Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991621/opencv-on-android-using-eclipse)

One option I would recommend using the Ketai library (https://code.google.com/p/ketai/) to do the heavy lifting for you. It has a camera class and a face detection class...